# How to fix this error extracting empty structure fields from a cell array when using cellfun()

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array in Matlab, with each cell representing a financial transaction as a structure object (the cell array is earlier imported from a json file).

Here is an example to create a test set which replicates the features of my data, representing 4 individual transactions in this case:

```matlab
transaction_1 = struct( 'created_on' , '2023-01-22' , 'amount' , 9.60 , 'merchant' , struct('name','ebay') );
transaction_2 = struct( 'created_on' , '2022-11-22' , 'amount' , 6.20 , 'merchant' , struct('name','ikea') );
transaction_3 = struct( 'created_on' , '2019-06-19' , 'amount' , 3.65 , 'merchant' , [] );

transactions = { transaction_1 ; transaction_2 ; transaction_3 };

% Add a fourth which is not "compatible" in dimension with the others
transactions{4} = struct( 'created_on' , '2019-06-19' , 'amount' , 1.25 , 'merchant' , [] , 'location' , 'London');
```

Each structure in the cell array contains three fields:

1. A date for the transaction
2. The amount of the transaction
3. The third field represents the name of the merchant. If there is no merchant information, then this field is empty. However, if there is info, then this field is another structure with the field 'name'.
4. Some of the structures also have a 'location' field as well.

The third transaction does not have merchant information in the test set, so `transactions{3}.merchant` returns empty, while the fourth transaction also has location data.

Now I wish to extract field values from the individual structures into separate cell arrays. The following code works correctly for the dates and amounts

```matlab
created_on = cellfun(@(x) x.created_on , transactions , 'UniformOutput' , false);
amounts = cellfun(@(x) x.amount , transactions , 'UniformOutput' , false);
merchant_names = cellfun(@(x) x.merchant.name , transactions , 'UniformOutput' , false);
```

but fails for the merchants because the name doesn't exist in some cases. Is there a nice way to do this without resorting to a loop over all entries?

Comment: You shouldn't put structs in a cell array. `struct` in MATLAB is an array type, just like all other types. Do `transactions(1) = struct(...)`, etc. Now you can do `{transactions.merchant}` or `[transactions.amount]`. Also, this is much more efficient, and you're guaranteeing that all structs are identical.

Comment: I would also argue against structs-in-structs, just because it's unwieldy. You could consider using `merchant_name` as a field.

Comment: I have only created it this way to replicate the data after import. The data results from the use of the built in function jsondecode(). I would not choose this format either, but this is what I have.

Comment: If the structs are all compatible, as in your example, you can do `transactions = [transactions{:}]` to turn it into a struct array. Doesn't solve the merchant problem yet, but it does simplify other processing.

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for your answer, but the after checking, the structs are not compatible, so I cannot run transactions = [transactions{:}]. Apologies that this detail was not included, and I see it makes a big difference. I have amended the test set in the OP to include such a situation. Sorry again.

Comment: I don’t have access to MATLAB right now. Can you not concatenate those structs? I think it should still work, or?

Comment: @CrisLuengo No unfortunately I receive: "Number of fields in structure arrays being concatenated do not match. Concatenation of structure arrays
requires that these arrays have the same set of fields."

Comment: That’s unfortunate, because then you end up using `cellfun` again, and that one is slow. Do compare `cellfun` with a plain loop, there’s a chance the loop is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a helper function to handle the different cases, then just use that in your `cellfun`.

```
merchant_names = cellfun( @(x) structValIfExists(x.merchant, 'name'), transactions, 'uni', 0 );

% >> merchant_names = {'ebay', 'ikea', ''}

function v = structValIfExists( s, fld )
    if isstruct( s ) && isfield( s, fld )
        v = s.(fld);
    else
        v = '';
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by extracting the `merchant` field to a cell array, and then processing that.

First of all, converting the cell array of structs to a struct array will make everything easier. Assuming all the structs are compatible, as in your example, then we can do:

```matlab
transactions = [transactions{:}];
```

We now have a 1x3 struct array. We can now easily extract individual fields into a cell array as follows:

```matlab
merchant = {transactions.merchant}
```

Some of the cells will be an empty array, others will be a struct. Let's find out which is which:

```matlab
index = ~cellfun('isempty', merchant)
```

We now create a cell array to contain the merchant names, and we fill it with the name where the merchant exists:

```matlab
merchant_name = cell(size(index));
merchant_name(:) = {''};
merchant_name(index) = {merchant(index).name};
```

Now `merchant_name` is the cell array:

```
merchant_name =

  1x3 cell array

    {'ebay'}    {'ikea'}    {0x0 char}
```